# Throw html content to the browser in gwt

Tags: gwt, servlets

I am using GWT and I want to throw the html content from the servlet. But when I invoke the servlet and throw the content to the browser its showing some exception:

```
GET http://127.0.0.1:8888/com.opt.opt/opt.css 404 (Not Found) 5C1C7AB6A2CE69634F1821FF011F5710.cache.html:1
GET http://127.0.0.1:8888/com.opt.opt/AppOpsClient.css 404 (Not Found) 5C1C7AB6A2CE69634F1821FF011F5710.cache.html:1
GET http://127.0.0.1:8888/com.opt.opt/MessageComponent.css 404 (Not Found) 5C1C7AB6A2CE69634F1821FF011F5710.cache.html:1
GET http://127.0.0.1:8888/com.opt.opt/com.opt.opt/com.opt.opt.nocache.js 404 (Not Found) 5C1C7AB6A2CE69634F1821FF011F5710.cache.html:1
```

and my servlet is throwing following content:

```
String html = "<!doctype html>"+
             "<html>"+
              "<head>"+
                "<meta http-equiv=\"content-type\" content=\"text/html; charset=UTF-8\">" +
                "<link type=\"text/css\" rel=\"stylesheet\" href=\"opt.css\">"+
                "<link type=\"text/css\" rel=\"stylesheet\" href=\"AppOpsClient.css\">"+
                "<link type=\"text/css\" rel=\"stylesheet\" href=\"MessageComponent.css\">"+
                "<title>demoopt</title>"+
                "<script type=\"text/javascript\" language=\"javascript\" src=\"com.opt.opt/com.opt.opt.nocache.js\"></script>"+
                 "</head>"+
              "<body>"+
                /*"<iframe src=\"javascript:''\" id=\"__gwt_historyFrame\" tabIndex='-1' style=\"position:absolute;width:0;height:0;border:0\"></iframe>"+
                "<noscript>"+
                  "<div style=\"width: 22em; position: absolute; left: 50%; margin-left: -11em; color: red; background-color: white; border: 1px solid red; padding: 4px; font-family: sans-serif\">"+
                    "Your web browser must have JavaScript enabled"+
                    "in order for this application to display correctly."+
                  "</div>"+
                "</noscript>"+*/
              "</body>"+
            "</html>";

response.setContentType("text/html");
            PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
            out.println(html);
            out.close();
```

Its showing this exception because its appending modulename i.e com.opt.opt to the css files and cache file. I dont understand why its appending the module name to the cache file when throwing the content to the browser. In deplyment mode as well as hosted ode its throwing the same exception.

Can anybody suggest me any solution. :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make your links as absolute paths (starting with the [`HttpServletRequest#getContextPath()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest.html#getContextPath%28%29))

Comment: But its showing the same error for script tag i.e for the cache file that is there with html.

Comment: I really dont know why its appending the module name i.e com.opt.opt while throwing the content to the browser.

Comment: I don't understand how you're using the response from the servlet and how the servlet is called, but maybe just try adding a `<base href="xxx">` in the HTML, or alternatively `<meta name="com.opt.opt::gwt:property" content="baseUrl=xxx">`

Comment: am calling servlet using the http://127.0.0.1:8888/myservlet and then I get the response from servlet itself. In the above solution what is that "XXX" .. :(

Comment: Oh, so you're typing `http://127.0.0.1:8888/myservlet` in your browser's address bar and your relative `href="opt.css"` link is interpreted as `/com.opt.opt/opt.css` !? The `xxx` in the `<base>` case would simply be `getContextPath()`, and in DevMode its value would be `/`; in the `<meta>` case it'd be `getContextPath() + "com.opt.opt/"`.

Comment: But even I deploy the the war .I have mapping in guiceservlet i.e serve("*.html").with(MyServlet.class);  so when I enter the url with .html extension it calls this servlet but same happens in deployment mode also.

Comment: So your problem seems to be that when GWT loads the `xxx.cache.html` file, your servlet generates your _HTML host page_ again, but this time at `/com.opt.opt/xxx.cache.html`, so a) the relative links try to load `/com.opt.opt/opt.css` as one would expect, and b) you've highjacked the `xxx.cache.html` generated by GWT so the app doesn't show. Try adding `<add-linker name='xsiframe'/>` to your `com/opt/opt.gwt.xml`, it'll then generate `xxx.cache.js` files. But clearly the problem is with your setup: simply don't map `*.html` to your servlet.

Comment: Thanks thomas-broyer :), the problem was because of of the mapping ,Now I changed the mapping to serve("*/redirect").with(MyServlet.class); and cleared the cache in the browser and it works fine :)